# Error in declaring variables in VB.Net 2019

Tags: vb.net

I'm not familiar with the syntax of the code in VB.NET and I want to use it to build the prototype of our system. I'm trying to practice some lines before I go with it and I'm having this error:

```vb
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dim Price As Integer
}
```

I got the code from the tutorials and the websites that I have visited but I don't know why it's showing errors, any ideas why?

Comment: You are using C# syntax to declare the method but VB.NET syntax to declare the variable. Here's an example of how a VB.NET method/function looks like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/function-procedures

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Also, I would expect a variable named `Price` to be declared as a `Decimal`, rather than `Integer` (even `Double` would be wrong).

Comment: Seeing that the compiler doesn't complain about the method, this is a C# project, not a VB project. You just need to start a new VB.NET project.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn While images of code are discouraged in most cases, I believe the screenshot was better in this case.

Comment: If I start a new VB.Net project, would it use the VB.Net syntax then?

Comment: Or is there any way that I can change its default syntax?

Comment: 2 things.  1) If your not familiar with vb.net why go down the route of writing a prototype in vb.net.  Surely it would make more sense to do this in language and tools that your comfortable in.  2)  You have to make a vb.net project to use vb.net code, this vb.net project and the functionality inside can be referenced by other project types like C#

Comment: "Or is there any way that I can change its default syntax? ", you don't want to change the syntax, you want to change the language. You can't code vbscript with C# syntax or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has mix C# and Vb.net script. The part `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is a C# code while the `Dim price as Integer` is a vb.net code.
To Fix your code please try this solution in C#.

`private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

`{`

```
    int price;
```

`}`

In vb.net code should like this.

`Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)`

```
   Dim price As Integer
```

`End Sub`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Okay will edit this for future references. Thank you

Comment: Adding proper explanation will be useful for future readers, and your post will be upvoted.